# Tabbed web part with documents in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part

Is there a **Web Part** showing tabs where i could add links to documents from a library?

My purpose here is to add a web part showing different tabs, different dates. And each of the tab would show a list of files of the particular year (not searchable on the site, i will just upload them only the ones i need to show).

I'm exclusively searching for a ready to use web part, i can't develop any solutions with jQuery.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: http://www.topsharepoint.com/dynamic-bootstrap-tabs-for-sharepoint

It is also pretty good explained.

I know, normaly not only links but the script is not that small.